# Jquery single appendTo from multiple appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, appendto

there's a way to improve this code:

```
jQuery('<img />',{alt:"Logo",src:"img/logo.jpg"}).appendTo("#scrittacentro");
jQuery('<h1 />',{text:'THE LCARS COMPUTER NETWORK',class:'cLightOrange lcars'}).appendTo("#scrittacentro");
jQuery('<h2 />',{text:'Authorized Access Only',class:'cDarkBlue helvetica'}).appendTo("#scrittacentro");
jQuery('<h3 />',{text:'Please Report Malfunctions To Engineering Staff On Duty',class:'cDarkBlue helvetica'}).appendTo("#scrittacentro");
```

On something like this:

```
jQuery(
    '<img />',{alt:"Logo",src:"img/logo.jpg"},
    '<h1 />',{text:'THE LCARS COMPUTER NETWORK',class:'cLightOrange lcars'},
    '<h2 />',{text:'Authorized Access Only',class:'cDarkBlue helvetica'},
    '<h3 />',{text:'Please Report Malfunctions To Engineering Staff On Duty',class:'cDarkBlue helvetica'
}).appendTo("#scrittacentro");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Try appending multiple elements in a single statement. i.e. remove commas and make one statement.

Comment: Yeah thank you but my question is: how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

In Multiple appendTo you are calling jquery constructor many times which makes the code slower and decreases the performance.

In single appenTo you invoking jquery constructor one time which increases the performance and doing the same work in faster manner

Check The comparison of performance http://jsperf.com/appendto-vs-multiple-appendto

**Single appendTo is better**

Your code can be minified

**js**

```
jQuery('<img alt="Logo" src="img/logo.jpg"><h1 class="cLightOrange lcars">THE LCARS COMPUTER NETWORK</h1><h2 class="cDarkBlue helvetica">Authorized Access Only</h2><h3 class="cDarkBlue helvetica">Please Report Malfunctions To Engineering Staff On Duty</h3').appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Thank you!
You helped me alot with this, i'd the problem yesterday and i don't know why this soultion didn't work, i messed up something maybe :)

Comment: I saw it but i will compress when whole script is end, will be long :) thank you really.

Comment: it's not the compressed version it the optimized code.If you are satisfied you can mark this post as answer